# REST Principles when applied to Pages of your application

Tags: rest, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am building an admin app that operates on items. For example, it's a registry of "applications". So the entity in this case is an "application" and /applications shows a list of applications, and allows for basic CRUD.

I am really enjoying the simplicity of REST and we use Zend Framework 2. One premise confuses me however, the idea of say GET http:[::1]/admin/applications should show a page that shows the LIST getList() of all applications. But how do we separate the PAGE, the header, footer, and other page related elements from the raw DATA representation of the list? If I requested GET /appointments with content-type json, I would expect JUST the data [ item, item2 ]. If I say HTML, I would expect JUST the html table. Just the fragment that is the data table.

But how do I say " I want the /applications PAGE?" that INCLUDES the list? Is this a separate notion? Every other REST action seems to fit nicely except the getList(), since the other parts are loaded as partials, say the form. I just want a controller that returns the form, and that form is injected via ajax into a dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you work with REST in a data-centric format. That is, JSON or XML. Those formats can represent data in a simple manner, without the overhead of user visible markup. HTML is markup and not suited for data representation. You do not often see HTML in RESTful interfaces, just because of this fact.

If you want to load HTML with your REST API, I would just ask for text/html and give the complete page back. Thus including header, footer, navigation and so on. There is afaik only one need for returning HTML without all those additional elements: that is in the case of XmlHttpRequests.

Most javascript libraries sending XHRs add a request header `X_REQUESTED_WITH` with the value `XMLHttpRequest`. In your application you can check for this header and if it is set, you only render the "applications" table.

```
class SomeController extends AbstractActionController
{
   protected $acceptCriteria = array(
      'Zend\View\Model\JsonModel' => array(
         'application/json',
      ),
   );

   public function apiAction()
   {
      $viewModel = $this->acceptableViewModelSelector($this->acceptCriteria);

      // Potentially vary execution based on model returned
      if ($viewModel instanceof JsonModel) {
         // Do some JSON things

         // Return the JSON
         return $viewModel;
      }

      // Do some HTML things
      $viewModel->setVariable('foo', 'bar');

      // Render only this view model if it's a XHR
      if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
          $viewModel->setTerminal(true);
      }

      return $viewModel;
   }
}
```

However, keep in mind REST is mostly seen for data exchange. If you have a REST api, you have a client in front of it to transform the data into html. Think for example about a javascript MVC framework like Ember or Angular.js.

You can mix html with a RESTful api to some extend, but try not to mix both too much. It's hard and you won't succeed to that extend. There're just two different architectural systems.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to separate page related elements from the raw data _if_the client request for text/html. If raw data is, say application/json, a client that wants to see them can request for application/json set in http accept header.

To help generating content based on the accept header, see [acceptable view model selector controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-acceptableviewmodelselector)

Comment: I think it is another concept, so I introduced a new route for "manage". WDYT? So now:
/applications -> just the list of applications
/applications/manage -> a page used to manage the applications (crud link list and more
/applications/id -> just the individual application
/applications/id/edit -> Edit form for that application
/applications/create -> New Form for an application 

All on the ApplicationsRestController exposes all these actions.

Comment: Just remember that URLs should point to resources (nouns), not verbs. Having said that, that's what I found myself is doing for some reasons (e.g. a link for download). Try to limit them to a few words, I use 'edit' instead of 'manage', 'delete' and 'create'.